# How to know how many new rows get inserted when using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Tags: mysql

I'm using `MySQL`'s `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature.

I want to know how many new rows are inserted, my current implementation is to `count(*)` before and after the `INSERT` and then subtract one from the other to get the amount changed.

But this is not working very well:

1. the amount would be incorrect if there are concurrent update going on
2. on large tables, counting twice would be painfully slow

So, is there a better way to know how many new rows are actually inserted?

Comment: @safinchacko Read the question again :P